# How to let Hibernate create tables in database automatically when used with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA, And for now I am trying to understand standard examples, I was reading online and saw a few stackoverflow questions, What I found in all of them is the following statement will allow hibernate to create tables at run-time.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

But Whenever I run my code without tables in mysql database, it throws the following error :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.4.RELEASE)

2014-07-24 09:44:25.365  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.e.r.simple.SimpleConfiguration   : Starting SimpleConfiguration on harmathu-WS with PID 8496 (C:\Songs\spring-data-jpa-examples\spring-data-jpa-example\target\classes started by harmathu in C:\Songs\spring-data-jpa-examples\spring-data-jpa-example)
2014-07-24 09:44:25.421  INFO 8496 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@429bd883: startup date [Thu Jul 24 09:44:25 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-24 09:44:26.722  INFO 8496 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-07-24 09:44:26.747  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2014-07-24 09:44:26.831  INFO 8496 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
2014-07-24 09:44:26.834  INFO 8496 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2014-07-24 09:44:26.836  INFO 8496 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014-07-24 09:44:27.172  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
2014-07-24 09:44:27.390  INFO 8496 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2014-07-24 09:44:27.571  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-07-24 09:44:28.392  WARN 8496 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker        : [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 97.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2014-07-24 09:44:28.567  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-07-24 09:44:28.591  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.e.r.simple.SimpleConfiguration   : Started SimpleConfiguration in 3.611 seconds (JVM running for 4.607)
2014-07-24 09:44:28.658  WARN 8496 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2014-07-24 09:44:28.659 ERROR 8496 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'test_auditor.app_user' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:172)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.example.repository.simple.SimpleConfiguration.main(SimpleConfiguration.java:45)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:289)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:389)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:390)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test_auditor.app_user' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 49 more
2014-07-24 09:44:28.674  INFO 8496 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@429bd883: startup date [Thu Jul 24 09:44:25 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-24 09:44:28.676  INFO 8496 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2014-07-24 09:44:28.678  INFO 8496 --- [       Thread-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I have application.properties as this :

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_auditor
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=<password>
################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Users.java :

```
package org.springframework.data.jpa.example.repository.simple;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

/**
 * Sample user class.
 * 
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Thomas Darimont
 */
@Entity
@Table (name="app_User")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByTheUsersName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u where u.username = ?")
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2952735933715107252L;

    @Column(name="username", unique = true) private String username;

    @Column (name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column (name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    public User() {
        this(null);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new user instance.
     */

    public User(Long id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public User(String username, String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getUsername() {

        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstname the firstname to set
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastname the lastname to set
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

     @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(
                    "User[id=%d, username='%s', firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                    super.getId(), this.username, this.firstname, this.lastname);
        }
}
```

Simple Configuration.java :

```
package org.springframework.data.jpa.example.repository.simple;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;




/**
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class SimpleConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(
                SimpleConfiguration.class);

        SimpleUserRepository repository = context
                .getBean(SimpleUserRepository.class);

        repository.save(new User("harmathu", "Harsh", "Mathur"));
        repository.save(new User("vibmathu", "Vibhor", "Mathur"));
        repository.save(new User("jackbau", "Jack", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new User("chobr", "Chloe", "O'Brian"));
        repository.save(new User("kimbau", "Kim", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new User("davipa", "David", "Palmer"));
        repository.save(new User("midess", "Michelle", "Dessler"));

        Iterable<User> users = repository.findAll();

        System.out.println("Users found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
        System.out.println();

        User user = repository.findOne(1L);
        System.out.println("User found with findOne(1L):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println();

        User bauers = repository.findByTheUsersName("chobr");
        System.out.println("User found with findByLastName('Bauer'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

            System.out.println(bauers);


        context.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is a Spring Boot issue and not a Spring Data JPA issue.

Try changing your properties from:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

to:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties

Comment: if you had a separate hibernate.properties file, then you could use them as you have.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like Hibernate did not create table because You've tried to create table with the same name as keyword 'user' (But You did not provide whole logs). Could You change the name of the table using @Table annotation to for example 'app_user'?

Comment: Hi,I did as you asked, but I encountered the same error. As requested, I have updated the question details with full exception logs.