# Tomcat started but the database tables aren't being created and localhost:8080 shows "HTTP Status 404"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm currently using the latest Spring Tool Suite (running on jdk 1.8) and I've downloaded the source code from the tutorial in this link: [accessing-data-mysql](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)

I tried running it using Tomcat and it shows `INFO: Server startup in 4581 ms` but when I accessed the link `localhost:8080/demo/all` , the page shows "HTTP Status 404" and the console didn't show any additional logs. The table "User" wasn't automatically created either when I checked my database.

I've just started learning Spring set-up from scratch and I'm feeling stumped... Thank you in advance for helping and any ideas on how to solve my problem would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating mine from scratch instead of importing an existing project. What solved the error regarding Hibernate not automatically creating tables is replacing this line in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

to this:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
```

I followed the suggestion on this link: [How to let Hibernate create tables in database automatically when used with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916810/how-to-let-hibernate-create-tables-in-database-automatically-when-used-with-jpa)

However, the link to the documentation provided was not found and the one who answered the question didn't explain it on his post.

Thanks to everyone who took their time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

404 Error is page not found error, so may be you are writing different url than what have you specified in controller.
Tables are not getting automatically created because you have not set the property:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

In application .properties write the following code:-

```html
server.port=8095
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=newuser
spring.datasource.password=newuser
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I am assuming that you are using oracle database.

Comment: Hi, I haven't modified any parts of the codes aside from application.properties, and the url I've been trying to access is indicated in the tutorial. I'm using mysql so I've modified the datasource.url, username, password and driver-class-name accordingly. I tried adding the server.port and the hibernate.ddl-auto configs from your snippet. However, the output is still the same.

Comment: Can you please show me your whole code ? If you can paste here its fine otherwise  upload your  code dropbox/onedrive and share the link with me, i will try to debug it

Comment: Thank you, here is the link: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz3qmu2pkoxkyaq/gs-accessing-data-mysql-master.zip?dl=0) I've imported it as an existing Maven project.

Comment: This is gradle project and you have imported it as maven , that is why you are getting error

Comment: Upon checking, the project allows either a maven or a gradle build.(Specifically pointed out in the guide as well as the eclipse setup here: [https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/](https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/) )

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MySql I would suggest trying this .properties configuration:

```
spring.datasource.username=<user_name>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db_name>?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
```

I'm using this on a few Spring applications and it works fine for me. This will auto-create the database and run the DDL to create your initial schema. Mind you that I'm using this along with a custom DatabaConfiguration class that handles setting up and managing everything. Somethig in the lines of:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("<where_repos_are_found>")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private static final String[] PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = { "<packages_locations>" };

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "spring.datasource.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "spring.datasource.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "spring.datasource.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DATABASE_DRIVER = "hibernate.connection.driver_class";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_USE_SQL_COMMENTS = "hibernate.use_sql_comments";

    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseConfiguration(Environment env) { this.env = env; }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DATABASE_DRIVER, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_USE_SQL_COMMENTS, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_USE_SQL_COMMENTS));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Also for any purposes I use hibernate's own properties instead of Spring's one so an example would be this one:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Finally regarding the 404 you're getting I think the link you're hitting might be wrong. I would suggest turning on the `debug` log property in order to better review your various mappings once the application starts up.

You can do this via setting `logging.level.<package_name_of_your_app>=debug`

Answer (score 0):

Do run a maven install if you are using maven or the gradle equivalent command and then restart tomcat.
I had the same problem. It works for me.

Hope it is useful.